# How to install module name with an underscore in python?

Tags: python, import, module, init, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to install the Levenshtein module, as you can see [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0).

I am able to run the `setup.py` file by `python setup.py build`.

Then, when I go immediately into python by doing just `python` from he terminal, while in the same folder as the folder `Levenshtein`, I try to import it:

`import Levenshtein`,

but I get the following error:

```
    >>> import Levenshtein
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Levenshtein/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Levenshtein import _levenshtein
ImportError: cannot import name _levenshtein
```

and, when I look in the folder `Levenshtein`, I see two files that are similar to that name:

```
 _levenshtein.c   _levenshtein.h
```

How does this import make sense, and how am I supposed to get a file of the name `_levenshtein`?

Comment: You need to compile them.  The module's `setup.py` script usually do this already during build.  If not, try `python setup.py build_ext`.

Comment: Why not use `pip`: `pip install python-levenshtein`

Comment: It doesn't do it automatically, or so it seems.  I'll compile them manually

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are confusing the pypi package name with the module name, they are not the same thing.

It is true that most of the time they are the same, as it makes sense to use the same name for both.

Still, about 10-15% of existing pypi packages will install modules with different names, sometimes multiple modules as part of the same package.

So, you have to find the name of the pypi package that is installing your module, that's all.

Comment: Can you give a fictitious example about the concept of different package name and module name please. And also - how user can find out what are the available module names in the package?